# Why Nuget Manager package so slow?

Tags: nuget

I was trying to update my **Nuget Manager**.As you can see in picture it is very slow . How to fix this?[image: This imagine des]

Comment: It's actually updating from internet, if this is slow then your internet connection may be slow as well

Comment: It can't be that slow normally. May be the internet connection is slow or server is busy at that time i guess

Comment: My internet speed 3mb/s. It's been running for over hours now

Comment: Use google speed test, to test your download speed. In this google speed test, it will try to download a 40 mb file and check the latency.

Comment: Tested and it says 4.15Mbps

Comment: What was the latency in the speed test ?

Comment: The Downloading of nuget manager has stopped entirely. it' stopped on 255kb

Comment: Can you restart your visual studio

Comment: The Nuget is gone. I cannot find it anywhere after restarting

Comment: What do you mean by gone, the update is not available for nuget or you cannot find nuget manager in visual studio ?

Comment: both of them: the update button and in visual studio

Comment: Can you go to Tools in visual studio and check if you have Nuget package manager there ?

Comment: the nuget package manager is gone everywhere..Looks like I have to reinstall my visual studio

Comment: No, Go to Tools -> extension and Updates, Navigate to Online , search for Nuget package manager for visual studio and download it.

Comment: Yes I found there nuget. But downloading speed is still very slow

Comment: Like I said, It must be something with out internet connection. Do you have any speed limiters/ antivirus programs which is limiting the speed,  installed on your machine, just wondering ?

Comment: And again it's  stopped on 79kb

Comment: can you use this lin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=nuget%20package%20manager&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Relevance to download correct version of package manager directly from the site and install it ?

Comment: I could not open this site. But I could open from my android phone! Why is that? if I will download how can install it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a proxy server? That may also be the reason things are slowing down.